# What is the exact name of the table in database in django admin?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-admin

Which one among the following is the name that belongs to my database table?

1. Tbl_categories
2. tbl_categorie
3. tbl_categories
4. TBL_CATEGORIE

**This is my class in models.py:**

```
class tbl_Categorie(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name =models.CharField(max_length=14)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

**This is the screenshot from my django admin:**
[image]

Comment: all of them are related to your model name

Comment: A database table has a particular name, not multiple names. I am asking what is the exact name that a DB table has in sqlite django admin.

Comment: If you need to find out the table from sql database why not check it out using some sqlite viewer?